How to run a .NET application inside a windows virtual machine ec2 aws?
I have a question regarding how could I run a .NET application (a simple server) inside a Windows Virtual machine using packer.
Here is my configuration:
This is the script that installs all the necessary dependencies for the VM:
# Install .NET Core Runtime
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1
.\dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 8.0 -Runtime aspNetCore

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1
.\dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 8.0
Remove-Item dotnet-install.ps1

# Check .NET is installed
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full').Version

# Set PATH environment variable to include dotnet directory
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)


# Install Git
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.35.1.windows.1/Git-2.35.1-64-bit.exe -OutFile Git-2.35.1-64-bit.exe
Start-Process -FilePath Git-2.35.1-64-bit.exe -ArgumentList "/SILENT" -Wait 
Remove-Item Git-2.35.1-64-bit.exe

# Set PATH environment variable to include Git directory
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

# Install IIS (Internet Information Services) if not already installed
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools

# Install Web Management Service
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Mgmt-Service 

This is the second script that builds the .NET application inside the VM
# Define the directory where you want to clone the application
$cloneDirectory = "C:\DotNetApp"
$iisDirectory = "C:\WebApiDeployed"

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $cloneDirectory -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $cloneDirectory -ItemType Directory
}

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $iisDirectory -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $iisDirectory -ItemType Directory
}

# Clone the application from GitHub
git clone https://github.com/biancapistea/webApi.git $cloneDirectory

# Navigate to the cloned directory
Set-Location $cloneDirectory

# Build the application
dotnet build

Copy-Item -Path "$cloneDirectory\bin\Debug\net8.0\*" -Destination $iisDirectory -Recurse

New-WebSite -Name "webApi" -PhysicalPath $iisDirectory -Port 80 -HostHeader "localhost"

# Run the application
# dotnet run

Here are my packer files:
This one builds the image on top of Windows Server and only installs the necessary dependencies:
packer {
  required_plugins {
    amazon = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
      version = "~> 1"
    }
  }
}

variable "aws_access_key" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")}"
}

variable "aws_secret_access_key" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")}"
}

variable "aws_region" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("AWS_REGION")}"
}

# "timestamp" template function replacement
locals { timestamp = regex_replace(timestamp(), "[- TZ:]", "") }

source "amazon-ebs" "autogenerated_1" {
  ami_name      = "packer prerequisites ${local.timestamp}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  source_ami    = "ami-0381840963c35cb1f"

  access_key    = var.aws_access_key
  secret_key    = var.aws_secret_access_key
  region        = var.aws_region
  communicator = "winrm"
  user_data_file = "./bootstrap_win.txt"
  winrm_password = "SuperS3cr3t!!!!"
  winrm_username  = "Administrator"
}

build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.autogenerated_1"]

  provisioner "powershell" {
    script = "./prerequisites.ps1"
  }

  post-processor "manifest" {
    output = "prerequisites_ami.json"
    strip_path = true
  }
}


The second one builds the image on AWS on top of the image created earlier which already has the dependencies installed.
packer {
  required_plugins {
    // amazon = {
    //   source  = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
    //   version = "~> 1"
    // }
  }
}

variable "aws_access_key_app" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")}"
}

variable "aws_secret_access_key_app" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")}"
}

variable "aws_region_app" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("AWS_REGION")}"
}

variable "prerequisites_ami" {
  type    = string
  default = "ami-0d0f70de1aeb0ce6"
}

# "timestamp" template function replacement
locals { timestamp = regex_replace(timestamp(), "[- TZ:]", "") }

source "amazon-ebs" "autogenerated_1" {
  ami_name      = "packer application ${local.timestamp}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  source_ami    = var.prerequisites_ami #id of the windows-prerequisites image generated by me

  access_key    = var.aws_access_key_app
  secret_key    = var.aws_secret_access_key_app
  region        = var.aws_region_app
  communicator = "winrm"
  user_data_file = "./bootstrap_win.txt"
  winrm_password = "SuperS3cr3t!!!!"
  winrm_username  = "Administrator"

}

build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.autogenerated_1"]

    provisioner "powershell" {
    script = "./application.ps1"
  }
}


Now when I create the load balancer on AWS using terraform (I use the image AMI created earlier, which has the installation and my .NET app in it) I try to access the DNS but I only see the windows server default website, not my .NET application. This is the link: aws-alb-1335693886.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
What could be the problem? How can I run the .NET application inside the image so that when I click on this link: aws-alb-1335693886.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com it will appear my .NET application?
Edit: I've attached a screenshot of how it looks when I open the EC2 instance on aws.


What you could do is try to RDP into the EC2 instance and check if the app is installed to the location you defined and if there are any error logs maybe.

Hello @MarkoE, I've tried to connect to the EC2 instance using a RDP on MacOS and the image contained the application along with the dependencies and I could run the server without any errors. But when I open the EC2 instance on AWS it appears only the windows server. How could I run the application and when I open the EC2 using aws to see the message "hello world" that my .NET app returns?

I assume the packer templates are in different directories or else the build would error. Are you certain the child AMI is being configured for the EC2 by TF? Are you certain the second PS script is behaving as expected?

@Bianca The screenshot you posted isn't Window Server, it's IIS's default page. Did you deploy your application to run under IIS or did you deploy it to run standalone? In the second case your application is running on a different port. Hosting under IIS requires some changes in the code and web.config

@PanagiotisKanavos I run this command
New-WebSite -Name "webApi" -PhysicalPath $iisDirectory -Port 80 -HostHeader "localhost"
which I think It creates an IIS, am I right? If so can you help me refine it a bit to be sure is correct?

IIS is the web server, like NGINX. What you posted created a new "web site" listening at port 80 but doesn't deploy your application. Try the actual deployment locally or in a VM first, following the IIS deployment instructions. There's no way you can just write some lines of script when you don't understand what IIS, web site, web.config etc are or how they work. Even experienced developers make a small mistake here and there and have to tweak a setting.

If you haven't worked with IIS before, why use it at all? Why not deploy the web app as a container? AWS has its own deployment tools for ASP.NET Core that could deploy with a single dotnet aws deploy --profile default --region us-east-1.

It would be better if you first package your application with docker. Use the image in your virtual machine, to start the application.
It should work.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
